# All preprocessing worsens accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am performing a grid search cross validation with a logistic regression model. I have my default model first, then one that should preprocess the data. The data are random text documents that fall into one of 4 categories. My preprocessor seems to worsen my accuracy and f1 score even when I just have it return the data, as below. The regularization parameter C the gridsearch picks after passing this preprocessing which shouldn't be doing anything.

```
Cs = {'C' : [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 10.0]}
gs_clf_LR = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(penalty='l2'), Cs, refit=True)
gs_clf_LR.fit(transformed_train_data, train_labels)
preds = gs_clf_LR.predict(transformed_dev_data)
#print gs_clf_LR.score(transformed_dev_data, dev_labels)
print gs_clf_LR.best_params_
print 'With optimal C, accuracy score is: ', gs_clf_LR.best_score_
print 'f1 score: ', metrics.f1_score(dev_labels, preds, average='weighted')
print metrics.classification_report(dev_labels, preds)
print

def better_preprocessor(string):
    #return re.sub(r'^[A-Z]', '^[a-z]', string)
    #return re.sub(r'(ing)$', '', string)
    #return re.sub(r'(es)$', '', string)
    #return re.sub(r's$', '', string)
    #return re.sub(r'(ed)$', '', string)
    return string


vec = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=better_preprocessor)
transformed_preprocessed_train_data = vec.fit_transform(train_data)
transformed_preprocessed_dev_data = vec.transform(dev_data)

gs_clf_LR.fit(transformed_preprocessed_train_data, train_labels)
preds_pp = gs_clf_LR.predict(transformed_preprocessed_dev_data)
#print gs_clf_LR.score(transformed_preprocessed_dev_data, dev_labels)
print gs_clf_LR.best_params_
print 'With optimal C, accuracy score is: ', gs_clf_LR.best_score_
print 'f1 score: ', metrics.f1_score(dev_labels, preds_pp, average='weighted')
print metrics.classification_report(dev_labels, preds_pp)
```

With some real preprocessing, such as the regex lines I have commented out, I also see a decrease in my accuracy and f1-score (plausible but I am getting rid of plurals and have been told this should improve my scores).

Answer (score 2):

Have you separated a randomly generated test set from you data, that exists outside of the cross validation, to test both models on? Accuracy decrease could be a result of greater generalization by reducing overfitting to the data.

Comment: that would be the transformed_dev_data and then the transformed_preprocessed_dev_data variables. Should I only preprocess the train data and not the test data then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your preprocessing basically does nothing, because preprocessing is what happens in CountVectorizer before tokenization. This means that you get whole texts through your function, and no regex with `$` at the end fires.

This is the result of fitting a vectorizer with your `better_preprocessing`:

```
In [16]: data = ['How are you guys doing? Fine! We are very satisfied']

In [17]: vec.fit(data)
Out[17]:
CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1),
        preprocessor=<function better_preprocessor at 0x000002DB839FF048>,
        stop_words=None, strip_accents=None,
        token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)

In [18]: vec.get_feature_names()
Out[18]: ['Fine', 'We', 'are', 'doing', 'guys', 'ow', 'satisfied', 'very', 'you']
```

What this means is that you have to override the `analyzer` step with your function, not `preprocessor`. Compare:

> **analyzer** : string, {‘word’, ‘char’, ‘char_wb’} or callable Whether the
>   feature should be made of word or character n-grams. Option ‘char_wb’
>   creates character n-grams only from text inside word boundaries. If a
>   callable is passed it is used to extract the sequence of features out
>   of the raw, unprocessed input.
>
> **preprocessor** : callable or None
>   (default) Override the preprocessing (string transformation) stage
>   while preserving the tokenizing and n-grams generation steps.

However, you will have to deal with tokenization in you function, but you can use the default `'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'`, so it is not that difficult. Anyway, I don't think you approach is really solid, and I would recommend using something like `SnowballStemmer` from NLTK instead of these regexes.